# Tkinter text block size

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I'm recently working on a task, but I've encountered some problems. The result I want is this:

[image]

The problem is:
The "place to type", should be immediately after my text, regardless of how long the text is. However, no matter what text I put, the "place to type" seems to remain in the same spot.

Long text:
[image]

Short text:
[image]

Here's my code:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Test")
window.geometry("1500x1000")

title = Label(window, bg="lightblue", fg="black", text="Test", font=("Times New Roman", 60), pady=5, width=window.winfo_screenwidth())
label = Label(window, bg="white", fg="black", text="Statement", font=("Calibri", 40, UNDERLINE), pady=5, padx=10)

content = Text(window, bg="white", fg="black", wrap='word', font=("Sans Serif", 21), width=window.winfo_screenwidth())
content.insert('end', "***The text I want to insert***")
content["state"] = "disabled"
content["highlightthickness"] = 0
content["borderwidth"] = 0

text_edit = Text(window, width=56, height=25, bg="#0e0452", fg="white", font=("Rockwell", 20))

title.pack()
label.pack(anchor=NW)
content.pack(anchor=NW)
text_edit.pack(anchor=NW)

window.mainloop()
```

I think it's probably because of the "content" in my code, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: please don't post images of code, on the bright side you have at least provided a [mre], the issue is that it is quite hard to test it because you can't copy text from image (not easily at least)

Comment: Hi Eden, could you please copy and paste your code in to your post as it is incredibly time consuming to copy out from an image.

Comment: does `content` need to be a `Text` widget? considering that it doesn't seem that users would use it anyways, it might as well be a `Label` and the issue you have is that `Text` widget doesn't shrink to fit its contents, it has a set size. If you worry about text wrapping: `Label` has a `wraplength` argument (in characters) or you can use the `Message` widget (which is sth between `Text` and `Label`)

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll edit it now

Comment: @Eden0516 great, still the same suggestion, don't use a `Text` widget, it has a set size, use `Label` (has a `wraplength` argument) or `Message` (just wraps text, but shrinks to fit its contents)